# How to add chat bot to the Skype contacts?? (for testing purpose)

Tags: botframework

I have created chat bot and integrated it to the Skype.
Its still under development. So I added contacts to with whom i'm testing it.
But When I click on Add to contacts, Its not getting added to their Skype. So I have to go to their machine, start their Skype and have to login to the bot framework on that machine and then it gets added to their Skype contact.

Is it defect? Or is this the only way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The `Add to Skype` link:

[image]

that you see in your dev.botframework.com portal does not require authentication. Just share that link with your test users and they will be able to add your bot to their skype contact list without you having to do anything,

Comment: @Pavel Veller How i can add bot in web skype? How i can add bot in skype runned with /secondary?